# Angular - using the form in the controller and in controller testing

Tags: angularjs

The docs specify that you can expost the form to the scope with name. so lets say I have this form:

```
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="submit()">
  <input type="text" ng-model="somemodel"/>
  <button ng-submit="submit()"></button>
</form>
```

but I'm trying to access the form through the controller with `$scope.myForm` and fail:

```
$scope.submit = function(){
  console.log($scope.myForm) // or form[0] or scope.myForm[0] etc.. 
  if(!$scope.myForm.$dirty){
    //do this and that
  }
//do something
}
```

they all fails as undefined. how is this done? ultimately I would like to also call `$setPristine()` from the controller. but I just can't find out where the form is hiding. is he even available to the controller or just in the view scope?

using angular 1.2.5

**EDIT:** this doesn't work also when the form name is with the dot notation: `myForms.myform`

**Another edit:** after forking the suggested [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/lGl7Q45X85nIDxc9SYrj?p=preview) I found out that the form doesn't exists on the `$scope` before submitting, but does exist after.
So I guess the **refined question should be:** is this the expected behavior? Is there a workaround this (in the ctrl and not in a directive)?

If this is expected and no workaround so I'll move the custom validation checks to specific directives - since in the directives (if they `require:"^form"`) the form is available before submit.
Thanks!

**Answer** this issue seems to be **when** the form is added to the scope. from the plunkers it's obvious that not in the beginning, but attached later, after the Parent Ctrl got loaded. can we control the loading order? I don't know. seems the place for this kind of form scope manipulation should be a directive and not the ctrl

Comment: I would expect $scope.myForm to work. Can you show more of the controller code/ng-controller html? Also `ng-submit="submit"` in the form tag should be `ng-submit="submit()"`.

Comment: -1 your example is clearly wrong and you have not addressed concerns .... @alonisser `$scope.form.myForm.$dirty` is not correct as stated by Matt.  If this is not the issue when you need to give us more markup so we can figure out if its a "chid-scoping" issue.

Comment: Since as you can see guys are right now trying to guess what might be still wrong with your code, providing a plunk/jsfiddle with a minimal non-working sample is indispensable. By doing that you additionally increase chances of getting the problem solved quicker

Comment: @nix AFAIK this isn't a child scoping issue - ng-show isn't suppose to create a child scope
the rest is old markup, which isn't the problem , just extracted a very simple example and maybe did a mistake or two while typing it, I know the if clause is wrong, as I state in the code the console log of every variant I could think about was  undefined.  no ng-controller in the form markup. the controller is attached by the ui-router view. and I can access the controller scope from the form, (and of course the controller updates with the form models..)

Comment: @nix  **the problem** I'm trying to figure out is how to access the form properties and methods (such as $dirty and $pristine) from the ctrl (I have a workaround passing it with the submit function, but that's an ugly hack) I may resort to doing it in a dedicated directive (where it does work when requiring form directive)

Comment: @alonisser the only way we can help is for you to show us more of the html that contains your form.  Your example above is still incorrect, what is keeping you from fixing it ?

Comment: @nix, I fixed the code above, and added a forked plunker from one of the suggested answer to demonstrate the problem

Comment: form exists in scope before submit, not sure where you get that idea from

Comment: @charlietfl look at the plunker, console.log the form on scope before submit ant get an "undefined", in the submit function = get the full form object

Comment: @charlietfl . at this [updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/B8U93yDEVV6V1zhYp6I2?p=preview) we can see that the form does exist on the Ctrl, but only after the Ctrl finished loading, thus encapsulating the call to ```$scope.myForm``` in a ```$timeout``` makes it appear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change the reference from `$scope.form` to `$scope.myForm`, then that is defined, as in [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/yMCGSkoYg2PH0qAVzF7W?p=preview). Unless you have a parent form called `myForms` that you haven't mentioned, you won't be able to  access it as `$scope.myForms.myform`.

Edit: the refined question asks whether it's expected behaviour that on the form's parent controller that the form is undefined when the controller is first run. The answer is yes, it's not added until later.

The question suggests that the form is only defined when the form is submitted. This isn't quite accurate. The form is added on the scope before this: there is nothing special about the submit function. You should be able to quite happily call form functions in response to other button presses. In the parent controller you can have

```
$scope.makeTheFormPristine = function() {
  $scope.myForm.$setPristine();
}
```

As can be seen in the following Plunkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/dDVrez9UP1GYRIDrUxJs?p=preview

Edit: from the comments, if you want a variable in the parent scope, say `notification`, to depend on a property of the form, you can setup a manual watcher:

```
$scope.$watch('myForm.$pristine', function(newValue, oldValue) {
  if (newValue) {
    $scope.notification = 'Pristine';
  } else {
    $scope.notification = 'Not pristine'
  }
});
```

You can see this at http://plnkr.co/edit/2NMNVAfw8adlpFRGuSoC?p=preview . However, I would be a bit careful about putting too much "view" logic into the controller. It might be better placed in the template, or maybe event a custom directive. This is probably beyond the scope of this question, and maybe better on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Also: I don't think you need the 2 `ng-submit` attributes, both on the button and the form, but I suspect that isn't related to this issue.

Comment: If this isn't the right answer, it would be very helpful if you can [fork the plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/yMCGSkoYg2PH0qAVzF7W?p=preview), or create your own, that shows the issue in action (as suggested in the comment by the comment from @vucalur).

Comment: Michal has proved the ability to access a FormController from within a Controller with this plunker, the issue therefore lies somewhere outside of the code snippet pasted in the original question.

Comment: @MichalCharemza I forked the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/lGl7Q45X85nIDxc9SYrj?p=preview) to show the problem. to refine - It seems the problem is that the form exists only after "submitting" and If I console log for the form before, It doesn't exist.

Comment: @alonisser The form's controller is added to the parent controller's scope _after_ the parent controller has run, so console.log would return undefined. Apart from console.log, what do you want to do with the form at at the point of running the parent controller?

Comment: @MichalCharemza let's say I have a use case -showing different messages to users depending on validation status before submit, or doing some "pre validation" that needs the server (checking for avaliable username). I know I can do it with a directive but I want to understand this behavior better. in this fork of the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/B8U93yDEVV6V1zhYp6I2?p=preview) I console.log the form on scope inside a timeout, to make it run after the Ctrl runs, and yes It does exist. So I would accept your answer.

Comment: @MichalCharemza the part I'm not comfortable about in your plunker is this line: ```  {{myForm.$pristine ? 'Pristine' : 'Not pristine'}}``` in index.html. won't scale for some dynamic message that needs more logic, and moving to much logic to the view. I know It's angularish and I'm doing this too, but I don't like it. I would  be happier with this kind of logic in the Ctrl , where the view would have only  ```{{notification}}``` that could depend on multiparameters - from form and ctrl

Comment: @alonisser I've added a part about setting up a manual watcher in the scope to setup a variable `notification` that can be accessed in the template. I would be wary of putting too much of such logic in the controller though.

Comment: @MichalCharemza this is a case where putting it in the Ctrl - puts too much "view" logic in the Ctrl, and in the "view" too much logic in the view. I think this is the classic use case for a directive - encapsulating view logic

Answer (score 5):

One reason you might not be able to see the form on your Controller `$scope` is if your `<form>` is inside a directive that introduces a new child scope. e.g. if the form is inside an `ng-if` or `ng-switch`.

In other words, in the example below, `myForm` ends up getting published to the child scope introduced by the `ng-if` and you won't be able to see it on the MyController $scope.

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
    <div ng-if="true">
        <form name="myForm"></form>
    </div>
</div>
```

One way to deal with this is to use dot-notation to publish the form into an object wrapper instead of putting it directly on the scope.

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
    <div ng-if="true">
        <form name="myStuff.myForm"></form>
    </div>
</div>
```

And in `MyController`, make sure an object is there so it will publish to it instead of the child scope.:

```
$scope.myStuff = {};
```

Take a look at this egghead.io video that does a good job explaining this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DTx23w4z6Kc

Comment: yes, It's inside an ng-show. I'll check if that supposed to create a child scope. I'll update

Comment: ng-show doesn't create a scope, so I doubt that's the issue :)

Comment: Thx @jonc, i was losing my mind trying to understand why my form wasn't showing up on $scope !

Comment: or `<form name="$parent.myForm"></form>`. Then using`$scope.myStuff={};` is not necessary. Access in controller is simply by `$scope.myForm`

Answer (score 1):

Oops. Just re-read your Question and realized that you are using the wrong scope path. As already indicated by Matt, the form will be pusblished to `$scope.myForm` and not `$scope.form.myForm`.

Comment: I tried both.. neither worked, maybe it is about the child scope as written below